# Could I use "when comparing" for this specific sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

> It's the iPhone 14 pro that really gets new features **when compared** to the older iPhone 13 and 13 pro.

Could I use "when comparing" for this specific sentence ?

If the answer is no , why "when comparing" can be used for this following correct sentence ?

> 1.When comparing the refurbished iPhone 11 vs iPhone  XS, it’s important to note that these are two very different devices.

Comment: Please. "that really has new features". It doesn't "get" anything.

Answer (score 1):

*Present participles* like "comparing" and *past participles* like "compared" are different parts of speech, and almost never have the same meaning.

It's a coincidence that in your first example sentence, both forms happen to be grammatically correct, and the resulting sentences happen to have the same meaning.

The original sentence means,

> "The iPhone 14 Pro gets new features when **it is compared** to the older iPhone 13".

When we replace "compared" with "comparing", the meaning is,

> "The iPhone 14 Pro gets new features when **you are comparing it** to the older iPhone 13".

So, yes, you *can* use "when comparing", but be clear the two phrases do not mean the same thing, as your second example makes clear. If we switch out "comparing" for "compared", the result is meaningless:

> "When **it is compared** the refurbished iPhone 11 vs iPhone XS, ..."

This is nonsense because "it" is the subject, then there's another noun phrase "the refurbished iPhone 11" which isn't connected to anything, so it's bad grammar.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, it helps me a lot. 
Anyway, it is said we cannot use "when comaring" in the first example sentence, since it says that the Iphone 14 Pro is comparing something. It is not. It is being compared with something. Someone else, probably you, is comparing the two devices.

Comment: @baktbd Who said that??? I don't see any comments or other answers on this question

Comment: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/about-compared-with-and-comparing-with.2351030/
@gotube this question similar to this one , vvujun said using comparing is wrong

Comment: @baktbd When you change "comparing" for "compared", the structure of the sentence changes so much that someone could think it was ungrammatical at first glance, but if you actually consider the resulting sentence, it is correct. So I could understand someone else saying that, but they haven't thought it through properly